# Exporting curved geometries as a GPKG with linear geometries

Tags: qgis, geometry, export, geopackage, curved

I have a layer (based on PostGIS or GPKG) containing complex, curved geometries (think `MultiSurface(CurvePolygon(CompoundCurve(CircularString(...)`.

How can I export this layer as a new GeoPackage that consists of linearized geometries?

With `ogr2ogr` one would use `-nlt CONVERT_TO_LINEAR` but it seems not possible to set that option in QGIS' export dialog.

I see that QGIS has a "Convert to curved geometries" processing tool but I am unable to find the reverse. "Convert geometry type" does not convert curves to linear.

Comment: Hm, "Segmentize by maximum angle" seems like a reasonable workaround. I would prefer something in the Export dialog though if there is any way.